# Using awk to extract a token from a larger JSON string

Tags: json, ruby, bash, awk, grep

I have a string assigned to a variable:

```
#/bin/bash

fullToken='{"type":"APP","token":"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"}'
```

I need to extract only `l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs` without quotes and assign that to another variable.

I understand I can use `awk`, `sed`, or `cut` but I am having trouble getting around the special characters in the original string.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was not awake I should specify this is JSON. Thanks for the replies so far.

EDIT2: I am using BSD (macOS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a [JSON](http://json.org) string there. Keep in mind that JSON is *unordered*, so most sed, awk, cut solutions will fail if you string comes next time in a different order.

It is most robust to use a JSON parser.

You could use ruby with its JSON parser library:

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | ruby -r json -e 'p JSON.parse($<.read)["token"];'
"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"
```

Or, if you don't want the quoted string (which is useful for Bash):

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse($<.read)["token"];'
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

Or with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | jq '.token'
"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"
```

All these solutions will work even if the JSON string is in a different order:

```
$ echo '{"type":"APP","token":"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"}' | jq '.token'
"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"
$ echo '{"token":"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs", "type":"APP"}' | jq '.token'
"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"
```

But KNOWING that you SHOULD use a JSON parser, you can also use a PCRE with a look behind in Gnu Grep:

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | grep -oP '(?<="token":)"([^"]*)'
```

Or in Perl:

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | perl -lane 'print $1 if /(?<="token":)"([^"]*)/'
```

Both of those also work if the string is in a different order.

Or, with POSIX awk:

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/"token"/){print $(i+1)}}}'
```

Or, with POSIX sed, you can do:

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | sed -E 's/.*"token":"([^"]*).*/\1/'
```

Those solutions are presented strongest (use a JSON parser) to more fragile (sed). But the sed solution I have there is better than the other because it will support the key, values in the JSON string being in different order.

---

Ps: If you want to remove the quotes from a line, that is a great job for `sed`:

```
$ echo '"quoted string"' 
"quoted string"
$ echo '"quoted string"' | sed -E 's/^"(.*)"$/UN\1/'
UNquoted string
```

Comment: Perfect! The JSON output has been coming the same for me so I did not realize that possibility would need to be accounted for.

I ended up going with this ruby solution since I need the string without the quotes: `$ echo "$fullToken" | ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse($<.read)["token"];'
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs`

It worked, but I have never used Ruby so would you mind explaining the parts of the code? Thanks again!!

Comment: Ruby is awesome. `-r json` adds in the JSON parser; `$<.read` slurps all the input; `JSON.parse()` parses the string read; `puts` prints the string with a CR. `p` prints a inspect version of whatever.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk -v f="$fullToken" '
BEGIN{
    while(match(f,/[^:{},]+:[^:{},]+/)) {  # search key:value pairs
        p=substr(f,RSTART,RLENGTH)         # set pair to p 
        f=substr(f,RSTART+RLENGTH)         # remove p from f
        split(p,a,":")                     # split to get key and value
        for(i in a)                        # remove leadin and trailing "
            gsub(/^"|"$/,"",a[i])
        if(a[1]=="token") {                # if key is token
            print a[2]                     # output value
            exit                           # no need to process further
        }
    }
}'
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

`l0ng_String` can't have characters `:{}`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed:

```
fullToken='{"type":"APP","token":"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"}'
echo "$fullToken"|sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: Only works if in the OP's order (JSON is unordered) and GNU only

Comment: @dawg If the source is JSON, then JSON tools should be used.  On the other hand, many things can look superficially like JSON and the OP didn't specify where his string came from.  The OP needs to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` method would be,

```
$ grep -oP '[^"]+(?="[^"]+$)' <<< "$fullToken"
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

Brief explanation,

- `[^"]+` : `grep` would extract the non-`"` pattern
- `(?="[^"]+$)`: extract until the pattern ahead of last `"`

You may also use `sed` method to do that,

```
$sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)"[^"]+$/\1/' <<< "$fullToken"
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

Comment: Not sure why I get a vote down, please leave some comments at least.

Answer (score 0):

If the source of your string is JSON, then you should use JSON-specific tools.  If not, then consider:

#### Using awk

```
$ fullToken='{"type":"APP","token":"l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs"}'
$ echo "$fullToken" | awk -F'"' '{print $8}'
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

#### Using cut

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | cut -d'"' -f8
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

#### Using sed

```
$ echo "$fullToken" | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]*)"[^"]*$/\1/'
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```

#### Using bash and one of the above

The above all work with POSIX shells.  If the shell is bash, then we can use a here-string and eliminate the pipeline.  Taking cut as the example:

```
$ cut -d'"' -f8 <<<"$fullToken"
l0ng_Str1ng.of.d1fF3erent_charAct3rs
```